# removing bullet and enemy ship from game when necessarry

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently writing a simple space war game, (a screenshot is available here : http://prntscr.com/2q9juj )

The enemy ships are coming from the right side of the screen randomly. I apply a `bullet.hitTestObject(enemyShip)` to check whether a bullet touches an enemy ship or not.

If it hits, I need to remove both bullet and enemy ship from game.(I've tried to just adjust its alpha value but not remove but after a bit time , my game starts to run to slowly)

So, here is my related piece of code :

```
for each(var bullet:Bullet_ in bullets){
    bullet.x+=2;
    for each(var enemyShip:Enemy in enemies){
        if(bullet.hitTestObject(enemyShip)){
            enemyShip.alpha=0;
            bullet.alpha=0;
            // I want to remove both enemyShip and bullet here.
                    //**EDIT: I solved my problem writing 2 lines :**
                      bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(bullet),1);
                      enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(enemyShip),1);
        }
    }

}
```

Is there anyone to helpme ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeChild' like so, (I don't know how you have added them to display list though)

```
for each(var bullet:Bullet_ in bullets)
{
    bullet.x+=2;

    for each(var enemyShip:Enemy in enemies)
    {            
         if(bullet.hitTestObject(enemyShip))
         {              
              removeChild(bullet);
              removeChild(enemyShip);

              //here update you array(s) accordingly 
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Rajneesh_Gaikwad I've one more problem, when enemy ships reach the left side of flash screen (I mean when they're no longer visible) I also need to remove them from my array, could I use removeChild also there ?

Comment: `removeChild()` only removes from display list and not from array. You have to remove them from array as well as set them `null`.

Answer (score 0):

***I think i can solve it, i do not know... but try this change:***

```
for each(var bullet:Bullet_ in bullets){

    bullet.x+=2;

    for each(var enemyShip:Enemy in enemies) {
        if (bullet.hitTestObject(enemyShip)) {
            enemyShip.parent.removeChild(enemyShip);                
            bullet.parent.removeChild(bullet);

        }
    }
}
```